# How to install angular project dependencies correctly

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, angular-cli

So every time I clone an angular project that has an older versions without node_modules folder and after that typing npm install to install all dependencies needed I get a lot of warnings and errors about versions.

This is what I get :

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is angular project version that I cloned:

[image]

This is my angularCLI version:

[image]

So my question, is there a way that I can clone any project that has older versions and install it's dependencies corretly without any error ?

Comment: When you try to run a project created on old angular on the newer angular version, you may and often get errors (incompatibilities, etc, etc). You should either install and use older angular version or migrate the project to the required angular version: https://update.angular.io/
Also please note, that Angular does not support migrating across multiple major versions at once. Please migrate each major version individually.

Answer (score 1):

`npm install`

Don't fix or audit any first; be sure project is fine before fixing anything.

Also make sure dependencies and non-dependencies match version stated in the cloned package.json

- `~version` “Approximately equivalent to version”, will update you to all future patch versions, without incrementing the minor version. ~1.2.3 will use releases from 1.2.3 to <1.3.0.
- `^version` “Compatible with version”, will update you to all future minor/patch versions, without incrementing the major version. ^2.3.4 will use releases from 2.3.4 to <3.0.0.